# How to replace EOS as core system token with some other(created) token for private network

Tags: eosio-code, eosio.system, private-blockchain

Is it possible to replace eos with some other token created from eosio.token contract and make it core system token

Answer (score 0):

We can change default symbol 'SYS' for private chains in our CMake file before creating eos build and changing "SYS"
[Here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/0d87dff8bee56179aa01472dd00a089b2aa7b9fa/CMakeLists.txt#L141) to whatever symbol lets say "ABC" we want to set for our private chain.
Also after deploying system contract we have to init it with our set symbol "ABC" like this
`cleos push action eosio init '["0", "4,SYS"]' -p eosio@active`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rebuild eos to change core symbol. Unlike initial version of EOS, core symbol is fetched from live network, so you just need to care about token contract.